# PHP-CS-Fixer - how to do not add curly braces on inline statements?

Tags: php, php-cs-fixer

I've started to use [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://mlocati.github.io/php-cs-fixer-configurator/#version:2.16) and I was wondering if there is any configuration to do not automatically add curly braces on inline statements, for example

```
//I want to keep this way
if (empty($var))
    throw new Exception('An error message..')
```

but when I format it turns into this:

```
if (empty($var)) {
    throw new Exception('An error message..')
}
```

My php_cs.dist config:

```
...
->setRules([
          'no_unneeded_curly_braces' => true,
          'braces' => [
            'allow_single_line_closure' => true,
            'position_after_functions_and_oop_constructs' => 'same'
          ]
    ])
...
```

Is this possible to achieve with PHP-CS-Fixer?

Comment: I understand that's precisely what the `braces` rule does. Are you setting it only to control the position of existing braces?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'm using "position_after_functions_and_oop_constructs" to keep class and functions declarations braces on the same line, but it shouldn't interfere other statements like if/else. So yes, I just want it to keep on the same line when there is already an existing brace.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález do you know if this is possible?

Comment: No, sorry. Otherwise I'd have posted an answer ;-)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález can I ask you one more thing? :D Do you know if there is an option to automatically add an empty line after class body?

Comment: Do you mean before the closing brace? I may be wrong but I think there isn't. Fixers are more focused on commonly used styles like PSR-2.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I mean the line after class declaration and before closing class braces

Comment: Read this: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/2780

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you can archive this with this small patch:

```
--- a/vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/src/Fixer/ControlStructure/ControlStructureBracesFixer.php 2023-09-11 11:08:29.382855161 +0200
+++ b/vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/src/Fixer/ControlStructure/ControlStructureBracesFixer.php 2023-09-11 11:08:26.158898572 +0200
@@ -202,7 +202,7 @@
             T_FINALLY,
             T_FOR,
             T_FOREACH,
-            T_IF,
+            // T_IF,
             T_WHILE,
             T_TRY,
             T_CATCH,
```

It simply ignores `if` statements in the curly_braces_position fix.

This solution is ugly but it works. And it won't be added to the fixer itself, as stated in https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/2780.